# pre-increment vs post-increment on std::atomic<int>

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, atomic

The common rule of thumb is to prefer using pre-increment on STL iterators in cases where the value is not immediately evaluated (i.e. you just want to increment the object/iterator). This is because in general the implementation of pre-increment is more efficient than post increment.

But what about std::atomic? If I run static analysis (using PVS studio) I get a warning saying that pre-increment should be more efficient, but when I look at the implementation of pre-increment (on Visual Studio 2015) it looks less efficient than post-increment?

Is there a general rule for using pre-increment over post-increment on STL atomic values or would it be implementation specific?

Comment: "it looks less efficient than post-increment?" How does it look *less efficient*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efficiency (at this level) is *always* implementation specific.

For example, as a counter to the rule of thumb "prefer pre-increment for STL iterators", it turns out that in practise few compilers will generate different code for pre-increment and post-increment.  (The spurious copy of the post-increment just gets optimized away to nothing.)

Comment: How does the generated code for post increment differ from the pre increment if the spurious copy is optimized away? EDIT: ah, you meant that it is rare that the generated code is different. I misunderstood.

Comment: @user2079303: It doesn't.  That is my point.  `it++;` and `++it;` will usually generate identical code.  (Of course, if you use the result of the increment then the code will obviously be different.)

Answer (score 4):

I don't have access to windows right now, but in gcc, the difference is between

```
__atomic_fetch_add(&_M_i, 1, memory_order_seq_cst);
```

and

```
__atomic_add_fetch(&_M_i, 1, memory_order_seq_cst);
```

which are builtins, so you can assume the compiler knows how to optimise it.

if you don't use the result, gcc -O3 yields

```
    lock add        DWORD PTR [rdi], 1
```

for both.

If you do use the result, then gcc -O3 yields

```
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-24], edi
    mov     eax, 1
    lock xadd       DWORD PTR [rsp-24], eax
    add     eax, 1
    ret
```

for preincrement, and omits the `add eax, 1` for post increment, so technically, yes, pre-increment is less efficient by one add, but in reality that is dwarfed by the sequential memory access.

TLDR: don't worry about it